# Does anyone know why this VHDL code is not compiling?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Does anyone know why this VHDL code is not compiling? (I am using modelsim)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.NUMERIC_STD.all;

Entity PartC IS
 Generic (constant N: natural := 1); 
Port 
(  A : IN std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
 S0,S1,Cin : IN std_logic;
  F : OUT std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
End Entity PartC;

Architecture CCC of PartC IS 
Begin
   F <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) srl N) when S1='0' And S0='0'
   Elsif std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) ror N) when S1='0' And S0='1'
   Elsif std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) ror Cin) when S1='1' And S0='0'
   Elsif std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) sra N);
End CCC;
enter code here
```

This is a part of ​16-­bit ​ ALU that accepts two 16­-bit input values `A` and `B`
and provides 16-bit output `F`.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: (vcom-1078) Identifier "unsigned" is not directly visible.
Cannot resolve expression type of infix expression.
** Error: (vcom-1583) Illegal type converson from 'unknown' to 'ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR' (operand type is not known).

Comment: Too many non-standard libraries, hiding numeric_std.unsigned. Delete std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned. (Also, some confusion between Else and Elsif)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be relying on the Mentor version of package std_logic_arith which includes srl, ror, sra etc. while the Synopsys version of package std_logic_arith does not.

There are two issues when using that package. First there's a syntax error where `elsif`s should be `else`s and second there isn't a `ror` defined with a rotate distance that's a std_logic (or std_ulogic, the base type).

Fix those:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;  -- Mentor

entity partc_mentor is
    generic (constant n: natural := 1); 
    port (  
        a:            in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        s0, s1, cin:  in  std_logic;
        f:            out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end entity partc_mentor;

architecture ccc of partc_mentor is
begin
    f <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) srl n) when s1 = '0' and s0 = '0' else
         std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) ror n) when s1 = '0' and s0 = '1' else
         std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) ror conv_integer(unsigned'("") & cin)) 
                                             when s1 = '1' and s0 = '0' else
         std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) sra n);
end ccc;
```

And your code then analyzes.  Note that `cin` is promoted to an unsigned array value by concatenating a null string. The qualified expression is to distinguish between concatenation operators where the type of the null string would otherwise not be readily apparent.

This can also be done using IEEE numeric_std derived packages. However `sra` got left out of the package before the -2008 revision, which also introduces package numeric_std_unsigned to provide the functionality found in Synopsys package std_logic_arith_unsigned and provides unsigned arithmetic on std_logic_vector values. (Mentor does not provide a comparable package).

Using a simulator or synthesis analysis tool (compiler) that supports the -2008 versions of the IEEE standard packages would look like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity partc_ieee is
    generic (constant n: natural := 1); 
    port (  
        a:            in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        s0, s1, cin:  in  std_logic;
        f:            out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end entity partc_ieee;

architecture ieee of partc_ieee is
begin
    f <= a srl n                    when s1 = '0' and s0 = '0' else
         a ror n                    when s1 = '0' and s0 = '1' else
         a ror to_integer("" & cin) when s1 = '1' and s0 = '0' else
         a sra n;

end architecture ieee;
```

This code also analyzes and depends on the to_integer function defined in numeric_std_unsigned. With no other concatenation operators visible with a right parameter that is a std_logic/std_ulogic value there is no need for a qualified expression.